# How to get the TFS workspace directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am trying to access the TFS workspace directory on my local workstation in my csproj file. I have the StyleCop files in source control and I need to add the absolute path. I created an environment variable and the does the job. I was just wondering if it was possible to get the path so my other team members would not have to do any manual configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As you can have many Workspaces locally, the first thing would be to identify which workspace do you want to get the path from.
After that, using the TFS API you can easily get the local path from the server path of your csproj file.
Building a tool that create/update a sysvar can be easily written, I don't know though if it suits you.

Here's the method you should call on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139272.aspx